# SFML can't create static sf::SoundBuffer* class variable?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, sfml

I am using SFML's audio libraries.

In my class I tried to have a private static variable that holds a SoundBuffer* as such:

```
static sf::SoundBuffer* breakBlockBuffer;
```

This gives a linker error when I try to build:

> Chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class sf::SoundBuffer * Chunk::breakBlockBuffer" (?breakBlockBuffer@Chunk@@0PAVSoundBuffer@sf@@A)
>   myprogram.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

However, if I declare it as an instance variable, it works:

```
sf::SoundBuffer* breakBlockBuffer;
```

This happens regardless of whether I dynamically link or statically link the libraries. It also persists in both SFML1.6 and SFML2.0.

I'm feeling that I might have made some silly mistake since I'm pretty rusty at C++, but the code looks like it should be ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a static variable in your class, you must also define it on your source file:

`foo.hpp`:

```
class foo
{
   static int bar;
};
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
int foo::bar;
```

Looks like you didn't do it.